# How can I compare a char to different letters in C?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char, compare

This is the code I have.

```
char ask_for_command(){
    char letter;
    printf("Command: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
    while(letter != 'a' || letter != 'd' || letter != 'w' || letter != 'x'){
        printf("NEW MOVEMENT: Enter a valid command by keyword:\n");
        printf("Valid commands: a d w x\n");
        scanf(" %c", &letter);
    }
    return letter;
}
```

The while loop works like this.

```
while(letter != 'a'){}
```

But not like this.

```
while(letter != 'a' || letter != 'd' || letter != 'w' || letter != 'x'){}
```

Can anyone explain to me why? Thank you in a advance.

Comment: What do you mean with “it doesn't work?” That's not an error description. What happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @FUZxxl like it does not let me accept any letters. Like I can type in anything and it will still print that the letter is not valid. It is meant to accept a, d, w and x. And return it back from the method.

Comment: You want to use `&&` not `||`. Run through your code with a simple example (such as input `a`) in a debugger or with a pen & paper. At some point, you need to learn to debug too.

Comment: @BlueMoon Thank you that worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `&&` instead of `||` for your comparisons. Think about it: `letter` is always unequal to `'a'` or unequal to `d`. If your letter is an a, it's still unequal to b, so it's unequal to a or unequal to b. What you want is a letter that is neither equal to `'a'`, nor equal to `'d'`, nor etc. Notice that neither α nor β is not the same thing as not (α or β).

It's also a good idea to either give `letter` an initial value (one you don't want, like `'a'`) or to use a `do`-`while` loop like this:

```
do {
    printf("NEW MOVEMENT: Enter a valid command by keyword:\n");
    printf("Valid commands: a d w x\n");
    scanf(" %c", &letter);
} while (letter != 'a' && letter != 'd' && letter != 'w' && letter != 'x');
```

Alternatively, you can use `strchr` for this purpose:

```
while (strchr("adwx", letter) == NULL)
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>` when you use `strchr`.

Comment: Thanks the '&&' worked. See the way I was thinking about it is that while the letter is not equal to either a OR d OR w Or x then ask for the letter again. Thanks again for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

I assume `ask_for_command()` asks the user to choose between `a`, `d`, `w` and `x`.

### Why none of your solution works

It won't work if you write:

```
while(letter != 'a' || letter != 'd' || letter != 'w' || letter != 'x')
```

Indeed, imagine what happens if the user choose `w` (for example):

```
letter != 'a' -> TRUE
letter != 'd' -> TRUE
letter != 'w' -> FALSE
letter != 'x' -> TRUE
```

Thus, the statement is:

```
while (TRUE || TRUE || TRUE || FALSE || TRUE) # You will enter the loop
```

The same thing happens if you choose `a`, `d` or `x` instead of `w`.

It won't work either if you write

```
while(letter != 'a')
```

Indeed, if the user type `w`, the statement is `true` (`w != a`) and you will enter the loop.

### What you should do

Do an infinite loop with `while`. As long as the user doesn't provide a valid command, you keep him inside:

```
char ask_for_command(){
    // Valid commands
    char commands[] = "awxd"
    char letter;
    printf("Command: ");

    while (1) {
        // You ask for the command
        scanf(" %c", &letter);

        // Is it a valid command? If so, we can return it
        if (memchr(commands, letter, strlen(commands)) != NULL)
            return letter;

        // It looks like the command given was invalid! 
        printf("NEW MOVEMENT: Enter a valid command by keyword:\n");
        printf("Valid commands: a d w x\n");
    }
}
```

EDIT: Using `memchr`, as FUZxxl mentioned in comments.

Comment: Have you downvoted me? Have you actually *checked* that the solution with `&&` doesn't work?

Comment: No I didn't. Also I don't think I have the reputation to do it.

Comment: `while (letter != letter_you_want)` does work, the loop is executed until the letter is equal to `letter_you_want`, which is exactly the behaviour OP wants. I assume OPs first example was the case where there is only one thing he wants to compare to.

Comment: Indeed, but I find the code cleaner using `strchr` as you did.

Comment: Except that the `strchr()` method actually has a subtle and somewhat unimportant bug: If `letter` is `\0`, `strchr()` will not return a null pointer but rather a pointer to the terminating `\0` byte. `memchr()` would be correct but this distinction is a bit confusing for a beginner so I left it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(letter != 'a' || letter != 'd' || letter != 'w' || letter != 'x'){
```

Is a loop that will never end. You probably wanted the logical AND instead of the logical OR.

AND in C is represented with `&&`
OR in C is represented with `||`

Thus, you should modify your code to this:

```
while(letter != 'a' && letter != 'd' && letter != 'w' && letter != 'x'){
```

This means WHILE `letter` is NEITHER `d`, NOR `w`, NOR `x`

Your original means:

WHILE letter is EITHER NOT `d` OR NOT `x` OR NOT `w`

Which is always true since something cannot be `d`, `x` and `w` at the same time